# Sorting Round Robin matches

Tags: php

I have a round robin algorithm for creating an array of matches between teams. Each match is played at the location belonging to the home team.

Once the matches are created, I'd like to move those where both teams have the same home location up to the first round(s).

Example array of teams:

```
$teams = array(
  'Team A' => 'Green Field',
  'Team B' => 'Blue Field',
  'Team C' => 'Green Field',
  'Team D' => 'Red Field',
  'Team E' => 'Blue Field',
);
```

And matches:

```
- Round 1
Team A vs Team D (Green Field)
Team B vs Team E (Blue Field)

- Round 2
Team A vs Team B (Green Field)
Team C vs Team D (Green Field)

- Round 2
Team A vs Team C (Green Field)
Team E vs Team D (Blue Field)

- Round 2
Team E vs Team C (Blue Field)
Team D vs Team B (Red Field)

- Round 2
Team A vs Team E (Green Field)
Team B vs Team C (Blue Field)
```

In this case, we would move **Team A vs Team C** up to **Round 1** because they both have the same location (Green Field). However, we'd then need to move **Team A vs Team D** somewhere else because each team can only play one match per round. In this example it probably wouldn't take many adjustments to work but when there is 10+ teams involved then it gets pretty sticky. Especially when there is more than 2 teams with the same home location.

Here is the actual round robin algorithm that I currently have implemented.

```
// Participant IDs are unique integer identifiers for teams.
// Example array: $participants = array(1 => 'Joe', 2 => 'Marc') etc.
$ids = array_keys($participants);

$count = count($ids);

// We must add a dummy participant for odd numbers
if ($count % 2) {
  $ids[] = 0;
  $count++;
}

// There are n/2 matches per round
$match_count = $count / 2;

// Create matches for each round.
// Example array: $rounds = array(1 => '01/01/2015', 2 => '02/01/2015') etc.
foreach ($rounds as $round => $date) {
  $temp_ids = $ids;
  for ($i=0;$i<$match_count;$i++) {
    // Pick 2 competitors
    $a = array_shift($temp_ids);
    $b = array_pop($temp_ids);

    // Only create matches without dummy participants
    if ($a && $b) {
      // Initialize the match
      $match = array(
        'date' => $date,
        'participants' => array($a, $b),
        'location' => get_location($a),
      );

      $matches[] = $match;
    }
  }

  // Move the last id from participants after the first
  $id = array_pop($ids);
  array_splice($ids, 1, 0, $id);
}
```

Comment: Can you show you algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would use:

Define 9 teams:

```
$teams = array(
    'Team A' => 'Green Field',
    'Team B' => 'Blue Field',
    'Team C' => 'Green Field',
    'Team D' => 'Red Field',
    'Team E' => 'Blue Field',
    'Team F' => 'Green Field',
    'Team G' => 'Yellow Field',
    'Team H' => 'Blue Field',
    'Team I' => 'Red Field',
);
```

Create 3 arrays to store all matches, all home locations and finally all rounds.

```
$matches = array();

$locations = array();

$rounds = array();
```

This is what you said you have: Get all matches. (I do also store the home locations of the teams for later usage)

```
foreach($teams as $team1 => $home1) {
    if (!array_key_exists($home1,$locations)) $locations[$home1] = array();
    array_shift($teams);
    foreach($teams as $team2 => $home2) {
        array_push($matches,array($team1 => $home1,$team2 => $home2));
    }
}
```

Then we sort the `$matches` array, so all teams with the same home location are on top.

```
usort($matches, function($a, $b) {
    $keysA = array_keys($a);
    $keysB = array_keys($b);
    return ($b[$keysB[0]] === $b[$keysB[1]]) - ($a[$keysA[0]] === $a[$keysA[1]]);
});
```

And then we can just loop over all matches as long as there are some left to play. We just use the possible locations as an indicator, if they are still free.

```
while(!empty($matches)) {
    array_push($rounds,$locations);
    foreach($rounds[max(array_keys($rounds))] as $location => &$match) {
        foreach($matches as $key => $val) {
            $keys = array_keys($val);
            if($val[$keys[0]] === $location || $val[$keys[1]] === $location) {
                $match = $matches[$key];
                unset($matches[$key]);
                continue 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you have trouble understanding what I did here, just ask and I will add some description :)

And this:

```
print_r($rounds);
```

Will give you this monster:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team F] => Green Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team G] => Yellow Field
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team I] => Red Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team H] => Blue Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                )

            [Yellow Field] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

As you only want to have 2 games per round, you can use the following (instead of the last `while`:

```
// set matches per round
$mPerR = 2;

while(!empty($matches)) {
    $keys = array_keys($matches[0]);
    $taken = array($matches[0][$keys[0]]);
    array_push($rounds,array($matches[0][$keys[0]] => $matches[0]));
    array_shift($matches);
    for($i=1;$i<$mPerR;$i++) {
        foreach($matches as $key => $val) {
            $keys = array_keys($val);
            switch(true) {
                case(!in_array($val[$keys[0]],$taken)):
                    $location = $val[$keys[0]];
                    break;
                case(!in_array($val[$keys[1]],$taken)):
                    $location = $val[$keys[1]];
                    break;
                default:
                    continue 2;
            }
            array_push($taken,$location);
            $rounds[max(array_keys($rounds))][$location] = $matches[$key];
            unset($matches[$key]);
            $matches = array_values($matches);
            continue 2;
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you (using your array example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                )

            [Red Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team C] => Green Field
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team E] => Blue Field
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Green Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team A] => Green Field
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                )

            [Blue Field] => Array
                (
                    [Team B] => Blue Field
                    [Team D] => Red Field
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this detailed answer. However, I'm a little confused about its implementation. I've updated my question with the actual round robin algorithm that I am using to create the matches. This is the best way to get an even spread of matches between participants and it also allows me to make multiple passes if each participant needs to play each other more than once. Anyway, would you be able to update your answer to adjust your code?

Comment: Can you add the whole code your using? because there are missing some arrays in the code you've provided

Comment: The arrays are just what you'd expect really. I've added in some comments to give an example of the data they would contain.

Comment: You can use that get_location() callback to return a teams location.

Comment: Yeah... but where do I know which locations are available? There is no "home location" to the participants